# SOAPUI: parsing xml FILE

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I have an issue with parsing XML file(not response. I need parsing from file)

So, I have file TRY.xml like

```
<!DOCTYPE request SYSTEM "URIWHEREDTD.dtd">
<request>
   <tag1>1</tag1>
   <tag2>2</tag2>
</request>
<request>
   <tag1>1</tag1>
   <tag2>3</tag2>
</request>
```

File can be really huge, It can be received NOT via soapui etc. So, I need to parse from file.

When I try

```
def inputFile = new XmlParser().parse("c:/TRY.xml")
```

it just returned

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException,...
Comment must start with "  error
```

I added that " to xml file, but new error is:

```
Content is not allowed in prolog
```

So, this is a problem...

Can anyone be so kind, and gimme solution for this error, or some other way to parse xml file?

E.g, in my "example" file I want to parse for elements(and get their values) for
tag1[1], tag1[2] etc.

Comment: It seems that it's not a valid XML file.

Comment: This file is went from response on call using *.dtd schema. And response received is just <request></info></request>

Comment: oh, here is misunderstanding. I gave just example, and there was  <respuesta> in Spanish in original XML. This is not "request", this is "response" in Spanish. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid `xml` file must have only a one root node, in your XML you have two root nodes `<request>`, you've to change your XML file to something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE request SYSTEM "URIWHEREDTD.dtd">
<root>
    <request>
       <tag1>1</tag1>
       <tag2>2</tag2>
    </request>
    <request>
       <tag1>1</tag1>
       <tag2>3</tag2>
    </request>
</root>
```

Additionally your error probably comes from the `dtd` schema, which is not shown in your question.

Hope this helps,

Comment: that gave me correct way for investigation, thanks dude.